# What's the purpose of `gl.deleteShader` in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, api, graphics, webgl

It's a sensible function in OpenGL ES, where such objects are referenced by unsigned integers. But WebGL is a JavaScript binding and it's by direct object reference: `gl.createShader` returns a `WebGLShader` (or null). Once all JS references for it cease to exist, eg. no longer in scope after the shader program setup, and the shader program is no more, it can be garbage collected, as there's no way to ever access or use it again.

So is `gl.deleteShader` a noop in WebGL, and if so, why was it ever adopted for WebGL? What are its practical uses? Is it worth executing it after linking the program, to free up resources earlier?

Comment: WebGL API conforms closely to the OpenGL ES API. Probably the `delete*` instructions are just there because they specified in OpenGL ES. However, they are less useful in WebGL. It makes always sense to free up unnecessary resources.

Comment: While there's little use for them, they're not noops as you can use them to explicitly free resources and thus excerpt control over the process in contrast to the garbage collector collecting and eventually freeing things.